# Gifting money to an Estate

Tags: united-states, new-jersey, trusts-and-estates

Can you make a gift to a person after they die? That is, can you give money to an estate? Are there any particular disadvantages to doing so?

I am thinking of the case where the estate is leaving everything to the person thinking about making the gift in an asset protection trust. Such a trust may also give divorce protection.

Comment: Does this just apply to gifts? There are estates that have incomes (royalties, IP rights, etc.)

Comment: One disadvantage is that you wont have the money anymore.  Seriously though, what sort of disadvantage?  It would make more sense if you explain your intent, i.e. are you looking for an advantage like a tax shelter?

Comment: It is hard to image any reason to do so? Maybe some suggestive facts could illustrate the motivation. Not ruling it out, and, for example, executors often waive their fees, but it isn't clear what is really contemplated.

Comment: @ohwilleke The motivating factor for making a gift to an estate could be so that the person giving the gift gets its back in an asset protection trust.

Comment: @MichaelHall The disadvantage I am thinking of is that the person making the gift may have to file a gift tax return and then have an add back when  he/she dies.

Comment: So you have outlined a couple possible and reasonable tax *dis*advantages, what might be the counterbalancing advantage(s)?  You are giving money away with the intention of getting it back:  Are you considering this as an investment?  If so the question might be a better fit on Money SE.